# How to Display only single captcha in imageview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have used Captcha Github Link https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-reCAPTCHA

but using this recaptcha library, Here in imageview both alphabetic & numeric captcha displayed but  m not able to display single captacha ??
So please do anyone have any solution or working example ?

Thanks a lot in Advance..

Comment: You want only alphabetic or only numeric  ?

Comment: na only alphabetic i want